# How to generate a a value for a field based on other field on Django models?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to generate a value for `name` field based on the `file` field.

```
class Files(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=settings.RAW_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH,
        null=True,
        max_length=500
    )

    def name(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am not successful when doing some Serialization/Deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add a name for the file being uploaded.

```
class Files(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=settings.RAW_IMAGE_UPLOAD_PATH,
        null=True,
        max_length=500
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.name is None or self.name == '':
            self.name = os.path.basename(self.file)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```